# Switch jdbc connection after Spring Cloud Config change

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-jdbc, spring-amqp

After successfully setting up a cloud config server and confirming that all works as expected I ran into this issue but I'm not sure if it's supported or the best way to go.

We follow the database-per-service pattern so as an experiment I committed a dev and staging file containing the db connection details of each service so that if we needed to make changes to the server address and credentials we only needed to do it in the config repo.

I have set this up correctly and I confirm that the changes are indeed being propagated from the config server to the clients.

It was only after doing all of this did I notice that even though the services got the updated database details it DID NOT switch its connection.

Is this possible? The only way I could do this was if I restarted the service and that kinda defeats the purpose of having all of this in place. I tried toying with the connection timeouts but it didn't help. The service was still connected to the previous connection.

Comment: There is nothing that happens automatically. DataSources have all sorts of things that would need to be recreated (pools of connections for example).

Comment: I was thinking that the unused/idle connections would just disconnect by themselves and when it reconnects it would go the the new server. Is this possible? @spencergibb

Comment: pools, was just an example, each DataSource implementation would be different.

Comment: From Twitter conversation: add request scope annotation to data source bean

Comment: I'm actually lost on that. I don't use a datasource bean. I just use the properties file to declare database connections details. Spring just works like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears a simple addition of the @RefreshScope to my controller did the trick. Thanks to Spring's David Syer for the insight.